# Mac Terminal command move files from subdirectory to parent

Tags: macos, terminal

On my Mac I amm trying to move hundreds of files on my NAS drive, from a parent directory with a load of subdirectories (and possibly directories inside them) and put all of the files into one folder. 
They don't have the same file extension for all the files.

Is anyone able to help with the terminal command I need to do this? So far I know that find . -type f will list all the files in the directory and subdirectories but Im unsure how to tell it to get them to move them all into another folder.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want.  This site is about programming and requirements capture is part of that process.

Comment: Not quite sure how you wanted me to be more specific as what I have said is pretty self explanatory - I want to know what commands I need to type into terminal to get all of my files out of a folder and the sub folders and into another folder, so therefore all of my files are listed in one folder. I assumed terminal commands were a form of programming so I apologise if they are not and Ive asked the wrong people for help.

Comment: Well you say the files don't have to have the same file extension.  So what file extension do they need?

Comment: Yes because I needed a generic code like '*.*' instead of extension specific like '.*jpg' because not all of them re image files that I needed to move.

Comment: You must get frustrated with the computer just not *knowing* what you want.  I guess that's the reason you asked the question.  Unfortunately computers, and us to a lesser-extent, need specifics.

Comment: However re-reading the question it looks like you want to put all the files that are in a file hierarchy into a single directory (flattening them, if you like).  Why the use of `-mindepth 2` in your answer tho?

Comment: Because thats what I found elsewhere after a lot of research and I assume it means the minimum directory depth of 2?

Comment: It's not important.  I think doing `find FolderA -type f -exec mv '{}' FolderB \;` will work.  Substitute the `mv` for `cp -f` if you want to be safe and have room.  That will copy *all* the files, regardless of extension.  If you want to more specific then use `-name` or `-iname` as per your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who may have this same issue:
Ive managed to extract just the .jpg's and put them in the parent folder.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -mindepth 2 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv -n '{}' .
```

Not quite what I wanted - I was hoping to get every single file and put it into a completely different folder if possible but this has got me further than before.

Comment: Your question says you wanted to put them all in one folder, now you say you want them put in a completely different folder? Different to what?

Comment: Blimey I knew I was bad at explaining things but I didn't realise I was that bad.
I have a folder - A with lots of sub folders in. I want all of the files out of folder A and subfolders and into a folder B.
I was trying to say I have got them out of the subfolders and into the parent folder A but I didn't know how to move them to folder B using the command line.

Comment: If you want to move all the files in `FolderA` to `FolderB`, make a backup first, then do `mv FolderA/* FolderB` or, equivalently `cd FolderA; mv * FolderB`

Comment: Many Thanks, I will try that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Go inside the source parent directory and use:

```
find . -type f -exec mv "$PWD"/{} <destination directory> \;
```

If you want to move all the files to parent directory itself, use it as the destination directory.